# digi scale Error

Tags: c#, device

I have program in C# which connect to the scale device (digi scale) the problem that i have is execption when the i set values to the properties of scale (unit price and tareWieght).
the exception that i get is

```
Error occured on SetTareWeight: Microsoft.PointOfService.PosControlException: Failed to set property TareWeight.
   at Microsoft.PointOfService.Legacy.LegacyProxy.SetProperty(String propertyName, Object propertyValue)
   at Microsoft.PointOfService.Legacy.LegacyScale.set_TareWeight(Decimal value)
   at Retalix.Client.SelfWeight.BusinessObjects.Devices.DigiScale.set_TareWeight(Int32 value) in c:\Project\CustomerScaleClient\Src\Retalix.Client.SelfWeight.BusinessObjects\Devices\DigiScale.cs:line 237
   at Retalix.Client.SelfWeight.BusinessObjects.Devices.Scale.ScaleLogic.SetScaleTareWeightByScaleManager(Int32 tareWeight) in c:\Project\CustomerScaleClient\Src\Retalix.Client.SelfWeight.BusinessObjects\Devices\Scale\ScaleLogic.cs:line 58
ErrorCode: Illegal
ErrorCodeExtended: 0
2013-01-17 12:31:46,789 [10] FATAL (Retalix.Client.SelfWeight.BusinessObjects.Devices.Scale.ScaleLogic) POS((null),(null)) InitialTrans(ID=(null), SEQ=(null)) 
Error occured on SetTareWeight: Microsoft.PointOfService.PosControlException: Failed to set property UnitPrice.
   at Microsoft.PointOfService.Legacy.LegacyProxy.SetProperty(String propertyName, Object propertyValue)
   at Microsoft.PointOfService.Legacy.LegacyScale.set_UnitPrice(Decimal value)
   at Retalix.Client.SelfWeight.BusinessObjects.Devices.DigiScale.set_UnitPrice(Decimal value) in c:\Project\CustomerScaleClient\Src\Retalix.Client.SelfWeight.BusinessObjects\Devices\DigiScale.cs:line 253
   at Retalix.Client.SelfWeight.BusinessObjects.Devices.Scale.ScaleLogic.SetScaleUnitPrice(Decimal unitPrice) in c:\Project\CustomerScaleClient\Src\Retalix.Client.SelfWeight.BusinessObjects\Devices\Scale\ScaleLogic.cs:line 76
ErrorCode: Illegal
ErrorCodeExtended: 0
```

i checked the proprerty `DeviceEnable` and claimed and they value true when i assign values to `UnitPrice` and `tareWeight`.

the next code was caused to the excption-
***//scale is digi scale*

```
var scale = deviceProvider.GetDevice<IScale>(); 
scale.TareWeight = tareWeight;
```

*i checked, before the assigment to TareWeight propertyת that deviceEnable is true –***

Comment: var scale = deviceProvider.GetDevice<IScale>();
 scale.TareWeight = tareWeight;

Comment: i checked before the assigment to TareWeight property that deviceEnable is true

Comment: can you breakpoint on the assignment line and look at what the scale object has for properties. You could be having a type issue. Is it possible to use `IScale scale = deviceProvider.GetDevice<IScale>();`?